# Compile error on cygwin with strerror_r

Tags: cygwin

I am getting a build error using `make`:

```
g++ -std=c++11 -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I../src/config   -I. -I./obj  -DBOOST_SP_USE_STD_ATOMIC -DBOOST_
AC_USE_STD_ATOMIC -pthread -I/usr/include -I./leveldb/include -I./leveldb/helpers/memenv   -I./secp2
56k1/include -I./univalue/include -DHAVE_BUILD_INFO -D__STDC_FORMAT_MACROS -std=c99 -D_XOPEN_SOURCE=
500    -g -O2 -Wall -Wextra -Wformat -Wvla -Wformat-security -Wno-unused-parameter -MT libbitcoin_co
mmon_a-netbase.o -MD -MP -MF .deps/libbitcoin_common_a-netbase.Tpo -c -o libbitcoin_common_a-netbase
.o `test -f 'netbase.cpp' || echo './'`netbase.cpp
cc1plus: warning: command line option `-std=c99' is valid for C/ObjC but not for C++
In file included from /usr/include/boost/assert.hpp:58:0,
                 from /usr/include/boost/range/size.hpp:23,
                 from /usr/include/boost/range/functions.hpp:20,
                 from /usr/include/boost/range/iterator_range_core.hpp:38,
                 from /usr/include/boost/range/iterator_range.hpp:13,
                 from /usr/include/boost/range/as_literal.hpp:22,
                 from /usr/include/boost/algorithm/string/case_conv.hpp:19,
                 from netbase.cpp:25:
netbase.cpp: In function `bool LookupIntern(const char*, std::vector<CNetAddr>&, unsigned int, bool)
':
netbase.cpp:95:39: warning: comparison between signed and unsigned integer expressions [-Wsign-compa
re]
             assert(aiTrav->ai_addrlen >= sizeof(sockaddr_in));
                    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~
netbase.cpp:101:39: warning: comparison between signed and unsigned integer expressions [-Wsign-comp
are]
             assert(aiTrav->ai_addrlen >= sizeof(sockaddr_in6));
                    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~
netbase.cpp: In function `std::string NetworkErrorString(int)':
netbase.cpp:720:41: error: `strerror_r' was not declared in this scope
     if (strerror_r(err, buf, sizeof(buf)))
                                         ^
                                         ^
```

Evidently cygwin does support `strerror_r` as per https://cygwin.com/cygwin-api/compatibility.html#std-susv4

Code snippet where the code is breaking:

```
#ifdef STRERROR_R_CHAR_P /* GNU variant can return a pointer outside the passed buffer */
    s = strerror_r(err, buf, sizeof(buf));
#else /* POSIX variant always returns message in buffer */
    s = buf;
    if (strerror_r(err, buf, sizeof(buf)))
        buf[0] = 0;
#endif
```

Can someone guide me as to how I can fix this ?

TIA

Comment: Did you `#include <errno.h>` ?

Comment: please show the compiler invocation with the full command line. `glibc` is a wrong tag as cygwin is not using it.

Comment: Adding via `#include <errno.h>` did not help....

Comment: Updated the post with the code snippet where compiler errors out....

Comment: @matzeri I have removed the `glibc` tag.... thanks